# What is the fractional part function of $e^x$?

Tags: functions, exponentiation

Given a real positive number $x\in\mathbb{R^+}$.

What is the function of the fractional part of $e^x$?

Comment: I could give the answer $e^x - \lfloor e^x \rfloor$, but I suppose this is not what you are looking for. Why exactly do you need this expression, and in what form do you want it?

Comment: @JohannesKloos sorry I missed your comment.

Comment: I was looking for another function that calculate the fractional part without having to calculate $e^x$. $e^x$ will be very large for the given x. So, I need a function that gives approximately the same fractional part with smaller numbers while calculating the result.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the Taylor expansion?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Taylor expansion. I will try to see what can I do with the following functions: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=E^x+Taylor+Expansion)

Comment: The Taylor series is the sum of x^n/n! for n = 0, 1, 2, ...; your link has an unrelated expansion.

Comment: I was trying to mention another page. For this query: "E^x Taylor Expansion". It contains it under "Series representations".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Johannes Kloos suggests, you can use the Taylor expansion. Here's the straightforward application; there may be better ones.

```
Let s = 0 and t = 1.
Start a loop with n = 1, incrementing by 1 each time.
  Let t = t * x / n.
  If t is sufficiently small, exit the loop.
  Let s = s + (t - floor(t)).
  If s > 1, let s = s - 1.
Return t.
```

Essentially all the rounding error comes from the t - floor(t). Some numerical analysis should give the maximum size of t and hence the number of significant digits in t - floor(t); this, in turn, gives an idea of what "sufficiently small" means.

Comment: The step "Let t = t - floor(t)." will reduce the size, but the result will be incorrect.

Comment: @Must: Oops, I stated it wrong. In my actual code I had a different variable holding the floored part.  Let me rewrite.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $x$ is between $100$ and $101$.  To compute even one significant figure for the fractional part of $e^x$, you will need to know $x$ accurate to about $44$ significant figures...

Answer (score 2):

The [Fractional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) [part](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalPart.html) of $e^x$ is given by
$\text{frac}(e^x)=e^x-\lfloor e^x\rfloor.$

Comment: I suppose this is the best answer one can give under the circumstances, but I do hope we get some clarification from OP.